# Javascript button delete

Tags: javascript, laravel

I had an issue with delete button.

ex: I press delete at driver 1 and choose no, after that I press delete at driver 2 and choose yes. driver 1 also deleted automatically.

here's my delete button code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#datatable tbody').on('click', '.delete', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-header h4').html($(this).data('title'));
    $('.modal-body p').html($(this).data('message'));
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable();
    $('#confirmDel').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('.modal-body input[name="_token"]').val()
            },
            url: url,
            type: "DELETE",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                datatable.ajax.reload();
                $.gritter.add(
                    {
                    title: "Record has been deleted succesfully", 
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {  
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        $('#modalDelete').modal('hide');
    });
});
});
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: Are you sure that's not a server-side problem?

Comment: Oh, may be you have to use `one` instead `on` to bind click event on __confirmDel__ button.

Comment: @AlessandroMaglioccola shouldn't a server-side problem. and I've tried one still not working.

Comment: How many times is called success callback function? Try to display an alert or debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same button with id ConfirmDel inside the modal?

Try unbinding the button event:

```
 $('#confirmDel').unbind('click');
```

Before binding it again:

```
 $('#confirmDel').on('click', function(e) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an event bubble. Clicking on child element will fire the

click event on parent element also.

try something like this:

```
child.on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: Is this your full code? paste out your full driver1 and driver2 code will help